# UiImagePicker custom part

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

in my app and I'm using UiImagePicker also implemented UiNavigationControllerDelegate for some customizations as the delete key and the back button.

When the user browses the images from its library and chooses one, if you AllowEditing is enabled, the image picker shows a screen for cropping the photo ..

At the bottom of this view seems to be a TabBar controller with two buttons:
Choose Cancel and

I wanted to know if anyone knows how to change the text of these buttons ...

Can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported API that gives you the ability to customize those buttons.

Perhaps the best solution is to find a custom replacement for `UIImagePickerController`. There may be one on github or Google code.

Comment: They told me that on ghitub Eglio would not go because you can not use codes made ​​by other users for copyright issues ... I do not know if it is true they told me so

Comment: I have no idea what Eglio is. I don't see anything on github with that name.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I expressed myself badly ... I use a translator for English ...

I wanted to say that I have discouraged some developers Ghitub because they say that you can not use ios codes created by other developers because they are protected by copyright and therefore say that it is useless ... I do not know if it's true or not .. I'm trying to understand

Comment: It depends on the license of any given project. Many projects have a license that specifically allow you to use the code in your own project. Be careful with projects that have no license. This has nothing to do with github. You should check the license of each project you wish to use.

Comment: Perfect thank you ... The licenses that allow total use of code what are they? so I better understand the differences

Comment: I'm not a license expert. You should read each license and see what it says.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy! beautiful link